# Error to call a web service on android device ionic

Tags: android, promise, ionic-framework

I'm trying to do a little login with `Ionic` and it works over the browser but when I run the application over the **android device** the application does not work.

So I've the following `LoginController`

```js
(function(){

  'use strict';

  app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope','$ionicLoading','LoginService','$state','localStorageService',

    function($scope,$ionicLoading,LoginService,$state,localStorageService)
    {
        $scope.title= 'Control de Rondas';
        $scope.spinner = false;
        $scope.renderError = false;
        $scope.data = false;
        $scope.pin = undefined;
        /**
         * Función que se encarga de llamar el servicio de login
         * @param pin Pin del usuario a logearse.
         *
        */
        $scope.login = function(pin)
        {
            $scope.pin = pin;
            $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Cargando...' });
            var login = new LoginService();
            console.debug('antes de enatrar');
            login.callService(pin).then(function()
            {
                console.log("here never entered...");
                $scope.data = login.getData();
                if($scope.data){
                  localStorageService.set( 'pin', $scope.pin );
                  $state.go('operador');
                }
                else{
                  $scope.renderError = true;
                }
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            },
            function(error){
              console.log("error");
              console.log( JSON.stringify(error));
            }

          );
        };
    }//end function.
  ]);//close the controller.

})();
```

I built my service that call a soap client to login

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Servicio que permite hacer llamado al web service para logearse en la
 * aplicación.
 *
 * @author Cristian Chaparro Africano.
*/
app.factory('LoginService', ['SoapClient',function(SoapClient){

  function LoginService(){
    this.data = [];
  }
  /**
   * Funcion para consumir el servicio de login.
   * @param pin del operador a logear.
  */
  LoginService.prototype.callService = function(pin){
        var url = 'http://cooldomain.com/web/app_dev.php/ws/loginOperador?wsdl';
        var soapMessage =
         '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><login xmlns="http://cooldomain.com/ws/loginOperador/1.0/"><pin>' +
           pin + '</pin></login></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';

        var soap = new  SoapClient(url,soapMessage);
        var promise = soap.callService();
        var self = this;
        promise.then(function(d){
          self.data = d;
        });
        return promise;
  };
  /**
   * Funcion que obtiene la informacion que retorna el web service y la procesa.
   *
   * @return String con la respuesta de acceso
  */
  LoginService.prototype.getData = function(){
    var result = this.data.data;
    var res = '<return>';
    var inicio = result.indexOf(res);
    var fin = result.indexOf('</return>');
    this.data = result.substring(inicio+res.length,fin);
    return ((this.data === 'allow-op') ? true : false);
  };
  return LoginService;

}]);
```

This is my SoapClient:

```js
app.factory('SoapClient',['$http',function($http) {

    function SoapClient(url,soapMessage){
      this.url = url;
      this.soapMessage = soapMessage;
      this.data = '';
    }

    SoapClient.prototype.callService = function(){
        var promise = $http({
            url: this.url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: this.soapMessage
        });
        return promise;
    };
    return SoapClient;
}]);
```

When I run the application over the android device I get the following error on console

```js
I/Web Console( 6061): {"data":null,"status":0,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://cooldomain.co/controlid/web/app_dev.php/ws/loginOperador?wsdl","data":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><login xmlns=\"http://cooldomain.co/ws/loginOperador/1.0/\"><pin>18485</pin></login></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":""}
```

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: What errors are you getting if any?

Comment: the problem is that never enter to the promise, and never call the web service

Comment: @hellyale, the promise works, but generate the above error, but just in the android device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the lastest Cordova version i.e. 5.0.0 you need to add the new [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) otherwise network requests are blocked:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```